# S.M.A.R.T results telling me that both SSD and HDD are dying?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, ssd, performance, hard-drive-failure

I have a question - are those S.M.A.R.T results showing that my both SSD and HDD dying? Did they fail?

Pasted it on pastebin to not make a mess here
https://pastebin.com/tXc3QsPu

Windows S.M.A.R.T cmd command shows that disks status is OK, CrystalDiskInfo shows it is good, but error values etc. are damn too high. Maybe it shows that overall they are OK because both disks, like rest of my PC build I've bought and built something about 1 month ago?

The results don't sounds good and I've suddenly got slow textures and draw distance loading and strange, most of play-time stutters in every game while overall framerate is OK (example 60-70 fps in Witcher 3 Novingrad city on 1080p/Uber/max postprocesses/hairworks on but low, during stutter it drops to 55 fps). Can't even rotate camera normally sometimes.
Before installing Windows 10 that things didn't ever happened.

That strange things started happening after going on Windows 10 from Windows 7. Clear reinstall Windows 7 didn't helped sadly now. I've saw similar question here, where guy too had disk problems after same Windows versions switching and stutters in all games happened for him at Windows 10 and didn't went away after downgrading to Win7.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't you think these problems could be related to your graphics card rather than to your disk drives?

Comment: damn, actually I've found out that my S.M.A.R.T. results are OK - actually most of stats counts down, so bigger=better. Probably RMA my GPU will be good idea if I will be out of ideas how to fix my problems, thanks.

Comment: Moving to Windows 10 again solved stuttering - game run smooth af again.

Answer (score 1):

Moving back to Windows 10 solved terrible stuttering problems.